# Apache Camel mybatis commits after every insert, want it not to

Tags: apache-camel, mybatis

I cannot seem to stop mybatis from commit() ing after ever insert, delete or update. I would like to control this myself

```
from( A )
(begin)
... do some processing ...
lots of 
.to( "mybtis:insertX?statementType=insertList" )

(commit)
```

and have written some mappings to do that, but after every insertList above and delete, mybatis immediately commits. I'm unsure how to tell it to stop doing that, and am worried looking through the source that commit() is built into those functions unavoidably in mybatis DefaultSqlSession for example seems to have commit() hardwired in (though of course it might be a mybatis-session commit rather than a db-commit, but hard to tell).

I might be able to achieve a similar effect with staging tables and things, but it seems messy and I'd prefer to use a correct mechanism if one exists

I expected it to be configurable on the mybatis configuration URI.

Maybe I just dont understand mybatis well enough to know how to do this

Comment: It seams to mu that `autoCommit` of `Connection` is set to true. Can you explain how connection is configured and are you using any connection pool?

Answer (score 0):

you are correct that each call to `.to( "mybtis:insertX?statementType=insertList")` will commit automatically, but you can pass in a List that you want to commit all at once...

```
from( A )
(begin)
... do some processing ...
... aggregate into a List ... 
.to( "mybtis:insertX?statementType=insertList" ) //commits once after entire List is inserted
```

see https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-mybatis/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/mybatis/MyBatisInsertListTest.java

Answer (score 0):

@boday hm, it seems I have lost option to 'comment'.

Yes, but this is the problem, I have such a large batch to insert that I need to split it into groups of 10,000 or mybatis breaks unfortuantely. I also do a table-delete before . I wish they left some kind of 'backdoor' for special things without a commit.

I have a feeling that I may need to use a staging table and do some kind of 'rename' to get the atomic effect I'm looking for sadly.

I'm going to have a look at getting the 'openSession' the other guy mentioned. It also occurs to me I could totally frig it with my own custom 'SqlSession' that overides the commit() method to just do nothing basically, and it wouldn't be so terrible because it would only be one method, but is obviously very non-ideal.